# How can I validate that a parameter is one of my Azure resource groups?

Tags: powershell, azure

In my PowerShell script one of the parameters is to enter an Azure resource group:

```
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, HelpMessage = "Enter resource group name")]
    [String]$ResourceGroup
     )
```

Is there a way using something like ValidateScript to make sure that this Parameter is one of the already existing resource groups in Azure?

If I add the Resource Group names into a variable like below is there a way to test that the parameter is one of the names in the variable?

```
$RGS = Get-AzureRMResourceGroup | Select-Object ResourceGroupName
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track with `ValidateScript`

I don't have an Azure set up so I can test but something like the following should work:

```
# This
[ValidateScript({$_ -in (Get-AzureRMResourceGroup | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ResourceGroupName)})]

# or
[ValidateScript({(Get-AzureRMResourceGroup | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ResourceGroupName) -contains $_})]
```

Comment: Great. thanks a lot for your response. When I get a chance to test it I will let you know...

Comment: Ok Tested. It works! In fact both your options do.. thanks a lot.